# apt update issue after port 80 dnat prerouting

Tags: networking, apt, 22.04

I need some help on making apt still work after pre-routing the port 80.
The config is as follow:

i Have a Debian server which Host an ubuntu 22.04 VM.
for some reason, i need to route the port 80 from public ip to the VM port 800.

So i added on the host the iptables preroute rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.100:800
```

All work fine, even the soft within the VM that use the port 800 from public IP.
but as soon as the rule is added, the VM "apt update" do not work anymore.

**If i remove the rule from the host, it is back working and can use normaly "apt update".**

during the issue, all ping on ubunut repositories are working, DNS is working fine.
just the "apt update" is failing. So i am missing something but dont know what.

```
xxxxxx:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::102). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::103). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here aresome more info:

- I do not use any proxy
- I am using google public DNS on VM and they are always accessible
- IPv6 of host and VM are disabled

Appreciate some help please

Comment: You need to specify the interface for your iptables rule. You want the rule to only apply incoming connections destined for port 80, but it currently applies to both incoming and outgoing connections to port 80.

Comment: @DougSmythies what you said makes total sense now that i think about it. Thanks it solved the problem:

Answer (score 2):

As advised and explained by Doug, I updated the rule to specify the interface:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.100:800
```

This did the job.